# What am I doing wrong with Numba here?

Tags: python, numpy, numba, dtype

I'm trying to learn how to use the Numba module. So far I haven't been able to get anything working because of some problem interfacing with NumPy. This is the code I'm running (from the Numba docs) and the error I get:

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(100).reshape(10, 10)

@jit(nopython=True) # Set "nopython" mode for best performance, equivalent to @njit
def go_fast(a): # Function is compiled to machine code when called the first time
    trace = 0.0
    for i in range(a.shape[0]):   # Numba likes loops
        trace += np.tanh(a[i, i]) # Numba likes NumPy functions
    return a + trace              # Numba likes NumPy broadcasting

print(go_fast(x))
```

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/JoHn/Documents/Current Classes/MEEN575_Optimization/HW6/Optimal_controller/angle_wrapping.py", line 84, in <module>
print(go_fast(x))
TypeError: expected dtype object, got 'numpy.dtype[float64]'
```

I know from some searching that this was or is a known error somewhat recently and had something to do with new builds of Numba requiring newer builds of NumPy or something like that, but as far as I can tell I have the most recent NumPy build, version 1.20. Any tips on what I'm doing wrong? To be clear I've never had a great understanding of how to cleanly setup environments in python so it is very possible I'm just missing something obvious here.

Comment: From [docs](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/glossary.html#term-type-inference): `Successful type inference is a prerequisite for compilation in nopython mode`. You should specify the [function signature](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/jit.html#signature-specifications).

Comment: Is this exactly your working example? This should work out of the box (which Numba version do you use?) Or is x some other array of dtype object?

Comment: I am using version 0.45.1, this example is copied line for line from the numba docs and does not work for me.

Answer (score 5):

Update to **0.53.1** works. It failed on 0.47.x as well for me. Seems more of numpy issue. One way to resolve install numpy >=1.20.0 and numba v>0.52.

More information on this issue:
https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/6041

P.S: not sure if you still have this error, just wanted to update, was facing similar issue.

Comment: If you have anaconda, it may stop you from updating numba unless you update all of anaconda together with conda update --all. (If this causes python to disappear as it did for me you can then do conda install --force python.app.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. I tried updating just numpy and numba to the versions that historically worked for numba (as mentioned by the other answer here), but that did not work for me.

What resolved the issue for me was a full update of conda and all the associated packages. I did that with the command

```
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

Be sure to restart the computer once you do this, since there are other packages updated as well.