# TypeError: expected dtype object, got 'numpy.dtype[int64]'

Tags: python, arrays, time-series, dtype, numpy-dtype

I don't know how to fix this issue and was wondering if someone could help me out?

Code:
**np.array(data['close'].tolist())**

After that when I run my code I obtain the following error:
**TypeError: expected dtype object, got 'numpy.dtype[int64]'**

How do I fix that?

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\nicol\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3343, in run_code exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns) File "", line 10, in  model.fit(init_pop) File "C:\Users\nicol\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tagenalgo\tagenalgo.py", line 310, in fit pop_fit = self._fitness_evaluation(pop) File "C:\Users\nicol\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tagenalgo\tagenalgo.py", line 246, in _fitness_evaluation fit_vals_lst.append(self._fitness_cal(ind)[0]) –
File "C:\Users\nicol\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tagenalgo\tagenalgo.py", line 201, in _fitness_cal idc = rsi_signal(self.price, rsi=rsi, buy_sig=buy_sig, sell_sig=sell_sig, error_tol=sig_tol) TypeError: expected dtype object, got 'numpy.dtype[int64]'

### data sample:
Timestamp, Close

2016-01-04 14:15:00,2.3552
2016-01-04 14:30:00,2.34595
2016-01-04 14:45:00,2.34105
2016-01-04 15:00:00,2.32945

Comment: hi, can you provide the full traceback of the error and also a sample of the data i.e., a [mcve]? And do you use [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) at all? If so, did you look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67016356/what-am-i-doing-wrong-with-numba-here)?

Comment: `data[‘close’].values.tolist()` perhaps?

Comment: data[‘close’].values.tolist() does not work either...

Comment: I don't use numba but I am gonna check that ! Thanks

Comment: Last thing: I have this error when I try to use the package tagenalgo: https://github.com/mick-liu/tagenalgo